Update objects in array held in Dynamo DB
I am creating a placeholder entry in my DynamoDB with a format such as
id: string
created_at: string
results: array

My plan was to add to the results array of data as and when I get said result objects.
Initially, the placeholder entry had the results being just an empty array [] and I was using list_append(RESULTS, :results) to do this, which worked great.
However I have now changed the structure of the results array being stored, and the placeholder will now contain a bit of extra detail per object stored; so my results placeholder will look something like:
results: [
  {
    groupId: 'group1',
    someId: 'abc123',
    otherInfo: 'some other info',
    results: []
  },
  {
    groupId: 'group1',
    someId: 'poi231',
    otherInfo: 'some other info',
    results: []
  },
  {
    groupId: 'group2',
    someId: 'oiy233',
    otherInfo: 'some other info',
    results: []
  },
  ...
]

and I will now aim to put the result objects received into the results array of each object in which I can match the id of the placeholder to the result data received.
Result expected
{
  results: [
    // result object 1
    // result object 2
  ],
  otherDetails: {
    someId: 'abc123'
  }
}

How would one go about most effectively adding to these object arrays?
Would I have to pull the results, iterate through and then persist the full set of results back? Or is there a way in which I can do a simple update like I was previously with list_append?
Initial thought was to filter the db placeholder by someId and then replace the empty results array with the results array in the received data.

I don't like this design as it means you need to understand the position in the list for each result set. Its much cleaner and more beneficial to use a map:
results: {
  'result-1': {
    otherInfo: 'some other info',
    results: []
  }, 
  'result-2': {
    otherInfo: 'some other info',
    results: []
  }
}

Now when I need to add results to result-1 object I can simply use list.append():
list_append(RESULTS['result-1']['results'], :results)

I no longer need to know its position, as I know its key result-1 or result-2 or result-n....

Thanks for the input on this. I believe I tried to use a map but the Pulumi setup didn't like it for some reason. I can always give it another go, as your suggestion does seem to be an interesting one to still use the list_append.

I have looked back at the data structures and updated the Q to reflect it better. The result key you have used is more of a group ID which can have different services. I see that we could something similar perhaps by grouping by this group ID and having the service as the differentiator (assuming there are no duplicates).

I suggest you create a new question rather than re-write an existing one.
